Can't run extention on selenium headless mode?
When I run the script extension is not working, when I check the error screenshot there are some ads.
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

extension_path = "/Users/user_name/code/webscrape/uBlock-Origin.crx" # Add block
service = Service("/Users/user_name/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver")
chrome_options = Options()

# Set the headless option and window size

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_extension(extension_path)
>! Also tried chrome_options.add_extension(f'--load-extension={extension_path}') it's not working
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

Extention is working on GUI (UI) opened mode but not on headless mode. Is there any solution for this?
Tried a couple of ways to run Adblock extention but I'm still seeing ads, while I dismiss adds on normal testing chrome?

You can add below code in your script and try
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_extension('Adblock-Plus_v6.1.1.crx') //you can use any version of Adblock-plus
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chromeOptions)


Found out this work around
Configuring Google Chrome for Headless Mode with Extensions
To enable extensions in Google Chrome's headless mode, follow these steps. These instructions assume you're using a macOS system.
Step 1: Create a Custom Profile Directory

Open your Terminal application.

Execute the following command to start Chrome with a new user profile:


/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile_Test"

Replace <your_username> with your actual macOS username. This command opens Google Chrome and creates a new profile directory at the specified path.
your browser will be in

Step 2: Manually Add Extensions

Simply go to web store and download the desired extension.

Step 3: Code implementation
from selenium import webdriver

extension_path = "/Users/your_username/code/webscrape/uBlock-Origin.crx"  # Add block
    chrome_options.add_extension(extension_path)
    chrome_options.add_argument(
        "user-data-dir=/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile_Test"
    )

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

Conclusion
When I tried to only implement the add_extension argument it didn't worked for me, then I found out that we can download the extension by opening chrome from terminal with new profile and install the desired extension, also you need to adress the extension_path too otherwise it won't work.
